# Alternative way to write gcc attributes for functions for C++ functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

Is there an alternative to write this in C++? I am curious if there is a way to maintain the readability without using the pre-processor macro. This is C++ 2014.

```
#define FUNC_ATTRIBUTE __inline__ __other_attribute___

void FUNC_ATTRIBUTE FUNC_NAME(void);
```

Comment: What is `__other_attribute___` exactly?

Comment: Just other compiler attributes that you can add to the functions. I just wanted to post a generic example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there is. You can replace all usages of a macro with the text that the macro would have expanded to. So in this case you can equally well write:

```
void __inline__ __other_attribute___
FUNC_NAME(void);
```

Note that you should never use `__inline__` in standard C++. Use the keyword `inline` instead.

Comment: What about `[[other_attribute]]` ?

Comment: @Geoffroy If "other_attribute" is a standard attribute, then that is an option (since C++11). Otherwise you need to prefix the attribute with an implementation defined "namespace": `[[gnu::other_attribute]]`. Also, the standard attribute syntax only allows to put the attribute before the return type; not after.

Comment: I would like to aliases out the attributes because these common attributes would be applied to a lot of the function. It also makes it a little bit more readable and portable with the macro.

Comment: @GeorgeWu You can use a macro for that. There are no other language features for such alias.

Comment: Thanks @eerorika. I wanted to know if C++ provided an alternative to this. Especially since C++ has several language features that remove most of the use cases for macro.